# Как игнорировать копии при DropAction в QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, drag-n-drop

Есть два QListWidget. Я копирую элементы из одного во второй. Второй должен содержать только уникальные элементы. Как мне это делать?

Нужно как-то перехватывать элементы, которые я дроваю и проверять их и если они уже есть во втором QListWidget то игнорировать эти элементы. Не понимаю как это сделать. Есть идеи?

Вот как задан первый QListWidget

```
    user_panel_buttons = new QListWidget(nullptr);
    user_panel_buttons->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
    user_panel_buttons->setDragEnabled(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setAcceptDrops(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::DropAction::CopyAction);
```

Comment: У ваших перетаскиваемых элементов должны быть какие-то уникальные идентификаторы (id, имена, типы и так далее), по которым вы будете определять есть уже такие, или нет

Comment: что в dropEvent прописываете?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Можете привести пример кода? Сейчас я добавляю элементы без идентификаторов. Просто через 
QListWidgetItem *listitem = new QListWidgetItem();
                QString path = "some path"
                QIcon image = QIcon(path);
                QString button_name = "name"
                listitem->setText(button_name);
                listitem->setIcon(image);
                user_panel_buttons->addItem(listitem);

Comment: Покажите как вы драгаете и дропаете

Comment: Никак, я импользую дефолтный класс QListWidget и устанавливаю флаги     user_panel_buttons->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
    user_panel_buttons->setDragEnabled(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setAcceptDrops(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::DropAction::CopyAction);

Comment: Я до этого пытался делать наследникак от QListWidget и там переобпеделять DropEvent , но у меня не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо создать наследника от `QListWidget` в котором контролировать "дропы", через переопределение поведения метода `dropEvent`.

Заголовник

```
#include <QListWidget>

class DropListWidget: public QListWidget
{
public:
    DropListWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) override;
};
```

Реализация

```
DropListWidget::DropListWidget(QWidget *parent):
    QListWidget(parent)
{

}

void DropListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    const QMimeData* d = event->mimeData();
    // есть ли данные?
    if (d->formats().isEmpty())
        return;

    // Получаем формат данных
    // Из другого QListWidget он будет таким "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"
    QString f = d->formats()[0];

    // Получаем данные, соответствующие данному формату
    QByteArray encoded = d->data(f);
    QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    // Читаем данные
    while (!stream.atEnd())
    {
        int row, col;
        QMap<int,  QVariant> roleDataMap;
        stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;

        // roleDataMap хранит значения, соответствующие разным ролям
        // нам нужна роль Qt::DisplayRole - тексты итемов
        QString elementText = roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();

        // Проверям, если ли итемы с данным текстом
        bool flag = false; // Признак обнаружения копии (по имени)
        for (int i = 0; i < this->count(); i++) {
            if (item(i)->text().compare(elementText) == 0) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // если не нашли, то добавляем новый элемент в список
        if (!flag) {
            QListWidget* sourceListWidget = dynamic_cast<QListWidget*>(event->source());
            // если источник это QListWidget
            if (sourceListWidget) {
                // Копируем иконку
                QIcon icon = sourceListWidget->item(row)->icon();
                // Создаем новый итем
                QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(icon, elementText);
                // добавляем
                addItem(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь надо добавить наш `DropListWidget` в окно.
Заходим в редактор `ui` формы, выбираем `QListWidget` и кликаем на нем <kbd>ПКМ</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В появившемся меню выбираем пункт `"Преобразовать в..."`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внизу вводим название нашего класса `DropListWidget`, затем нажимаем `"Добавить"`,
потом `"Преобразовать"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки списков такие:

```
ui->listWidgetSource->setDragEnabled(true);
ui->listWidgetSource->setAcceptDrops(true);
ui->listWidgetSource->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::DropAction::CopyAction);

ui->listWidgetDest->setDragDropMode(QListWidget::DropOnly);
```

Запускаем и пробуем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection не работает, работает для QAbstractItemView::SingleSelectio. В случае QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection, он проверяет по наборам, если перемещаемый набор ранее не перемещался, то он переместится . Даже если в нём есть уже копии некоторых элементов.

Comment: @VladimirChizh исправил код метода dropEvent

Comment: Теперь работает, однако у меня элементы с инонками, а addItem(elementText); иконку не добавляет. Обясните пожалуйста , почему вы убрали внизу dropEvent?

Comment: @VladimirChizh я и не должен был его добавлять, у него другая логика работы для множественного переноса (отличная от того, что нам надо - это мой недосмотр). Сейчас переделаю для иконок...

Comment: @VladimirChizh готово!

Comment: А как ещё можно сравнивать объекты QListWidget? Я обнаружил, что есть пара айтемов с одинаковым именем, но разными иконками. Надо ещё и по иконкам как-то сравнивать.

Comment: @VladimirChizh тогда легче итемам в источнике присваивать какой-нибудь уникальный идентификатор при помощи метода setData и сравнивать уже их `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData`. Но это уже другой вопрос "Как присвоить уникальный идентификатор QListWidgetItem", а текущий надо завершать (зеленой галочкой :) ), иначе он будет перегружен

Comment: понял, спасибо.